# Command line arguments not passing through correctly, argc always returning 1 and argc returning nullpointer on visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

I was recently working on a project for a class and was having a lot of problems with passing in command line arguments. I decided to test out with a really simple code I found online from geeksforgeeks to see if I could get any sort of command line stuff to work and it still is not working. It will not print any argv values and when I debug it, it says that argc is 1 despite me putting in 4 command line arguments. I have been trying to find answers to this online for hours and have no idea what is going on especially when using this really simple code. I attached the code I was testing below. It only prints out "You have entered 1 arguments:" I am relatively new to coding but very confused.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "You have entered " << argc
        << " arguments:" << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        cout << argv[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***I debug it, it says that argc is 1 despite me putting in 4 command line arguments*** In Visual Studio you set these under the Debug settings of the project properties for your executable project. Can you show that screen? `argc` will be 1 if you are passing no arguments. Edit: I uploaded an example from a work project: [https://ibb.co/th546mp](https://ibb.co/th546mp)

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: Where did you put the command line arguments? Are you running your program from the command line? Or from the IDE?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. If you get `argc` equal to 1 the problem is how you are adding the command line arguments.

Comment: Where are your command line arguments? And is your OS Linux or something else?

Comment: @drescherjm this is a link to what my command line arguments look like https://ibb.co/kSQnd0H I just put a space between each argument, I tried it with quotations on each argument and that didn't work either. I ran it on the command line and it worked so it must be an issue with how I am putting my arguments into visual studio. I could not find any good resources online showing how to format arguments so I am not entirely sure what to change. Thank you for your help so far

Comment: ***I just put a space between each argument*** That is correct. The quotes I used in my  example are for a more complicated command line processing where a single argument can have a space in it.

Comment: I see that you are running release mode. You may want to switch to debug mode. Set the arguments for that and debug. Place a breakpoint in the beginning of main by navigating to this line: `cout << "You have entered "`  and pressing the F9 key. Then you can run your code by pressing the F5 key. When the debugger stops on this line inspect the `argc` and argv[] variables. They should be in a `local` window

Comment: @drescherjm thank you so much, I switched it to debug mode and it is working!

Answer (score 1):

*"it says that argc is 1 despite me putting in 4 command line arguments."*

In Visual Studio, the place for the command arguments is: *Solution -> Project [Right-Click] -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Command Arguments*. It is necessary to set the arguments for the tested Configuration / Platform.

In your case you set the arguments for "Release" configuration but not for "Debug" configuration. In case they are not in the right place, they will not be taken into account, **but the program will still print 1**. Explanation:

*(Your code)*

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "You have entered " << argc << " arguments:" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio (but not just), when you build and run a C++ program, the full path to the executable file, including the executable's name, is typically passed as the first argument (`argv[0]`) to the `main()` function.

--

Run without arguments. Output:

```
You have entered 1 arguments:
C:\Users\Amit\source\repos\Test\x64\Debug\Test.exe

C:\Users\Amit\source\repos\Test\x64\Debug\Test.exe (process 32592) exited with code 0.
```

- Project properties:
  [image]

[Non-VS Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/PKh4ujbO2)

--

Run with 2 arguments. Output:

```
You have entered 3 arguments:
C:\Users\Amit\source\repos\Test\x64\Debug\Test.exe
FirstArgument
SecondArgument

C:\Users\Amit\source\repos\Test\x64\Debug\Test.exe (process 32856) exited with code 0.
```

- Project properties:
  [image]

[Non-VS Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/za6tBMkDx)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem - argc always 1. I tried Debug->myprojectname Debug Properties(at the bottom)->Debugging->Command Arguments and set my arguments there instead of Project->Properties->etc.

This worked for me. I am using VS2022 MFC and Win32(old x86 program). Hope this helps someone.